# Copy records from third table with foreign key to other table

Tags: sql, database, firebird

I have three tables: Table1 as master, Table2 as detail for table1 and Table3 as detail for Table2.

```
TABLE1
PK1 INTEGER, 
FD1 VARCHAR(100)

TABLE2
PK2 INTEGER,
FK1 INTEGER,
FD2 VARCHAR(100)

TABLE3
PK3 INTEGER,
FK2 INTEGER,
FD3 VARCHAR(100)
```

PK1, PK2, PK3 is auto incremented primary keys for table1, table2 and table3 respectively, while FK1 is a foreign key to PK1 and FK2 is a foreign key to PK2.

I need to copy one record from Table1 to the same table with all its detail records from Table2 and Table3.

I already did the copy for Table1 and Table2 using `Insert Into...Select...Returning` and I am thinking to copy Table2 and Table3 records inside `FOR Select`. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Firebird does not have auto-increment. Are you using a trigger and generator to assign a value for the fields?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what your question is. Why not just copy table3 the same way you did table1 and table2.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The problem is how to map all the old foreign keys to the corresponding FKs of the new records while copying.

Comment: I guess looping and using `INSERT ... RETURNING <ID-column> INTO ...` is probably the only way to get it working

Comment: was trying to avoid looping......thanks for every one time.

Comment: You can loop purely in PSQL on the server (in `EXECUTE BLOCK` or stored procedure) without roundtripping between server and client

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes I am using stored procedure already

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you really have autoincremented primary keys. More likely you use generators. If so then you may use this way of inserting data:

```
insert into table1(pk1, fd1)
select gen_id(g_pk1,1), fd1
from table2
```

if needed, you may use join or union tables in select query.

Just keep in mind to have proper output of your query to fit insert statement.