# Copy master and detail table in stored procedure

Tags: firebird

I have two tables master / detail their DDL are:

Table1:

- tbl1_id integer,
- tbl1_sm_id integer,
- tbl1_name varchar(30)

table2:

- tbl2_id integer,
- tbl1_id integer,
- tbl2_name varchar(30)

table2.tbl1_id is the foreign key between the two tables, tbl1_id and tbl2_id are generated automatically from triggers.

I need to copy all records from these two tables where tbl1_sm_id = 2 into new value where tbl1_sm_id = 3.

I tried this SQL inside stored procedure:

```sql
For
   select tbl1_id from table1
   where tbl1_sm_id = 2
   into :v_tbl1_id
 do begin
   insert into table1 (tbl1_sm_id, tbl1_name)
   select 3, tbl1_name returning tbl1_id into :v_tbl1_id;

   insert into table2 (tbl1_id, tbl2_name)
   select :v_tbl1_id, tbl2_name
   from table2 where tbl1_id = :v_tbl1_id;

 end
```

Is this correct? Is there another way to copy the two tables?

Comment: Isn't this very similar to the question you asked two years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886005/copy-records-from-third-table-with-foreign-key-to-other-table?rq=1 What exactly are your concerns and why do you want to know if there is another way of doing this? Your solution looks fine to me at first glance. You can tests if it really does what you need it to do (and therefor verify its correctness).

Comment: I dont remember, I just wanted some opinions thanks